# How can submit form data to my server and trigger a PayPal Pay Now button at the same time

Tags: forms, jquery

I am using a PayPal Pay Now button to let users pay for a product. I want to also send some data to my server when that button is clicked. Therefore I am sending those values by jQuery Ajax to my server. Unfortunately this works sometimes, sometimes the page goes to PayPal too quickly for the form values to be sent, and they never get saved.

The jQuery code looks like this

```
//...
function sendUserDetailsByAjax(orderId){

var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var arrivalTime = $("#arrivalTime").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/order/updateuser",
    data: { 'orderId': orderId, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'arrivalTime': arrivalTime   },
    success: function(data){
    }
}); 
$('#payWithPaypal').submit();   
}
//...
```

These are the form fields:

```
<input id="arrivalTime" type="text" size="12" class="checkoutInput"/>
<input id="name" type="text" size="32" class="checkoutInput"/>
<input id="phone" type="text" size="32" class="checkoutInput"/>
```

And here is the PayPal form (the ${something} elements are variables being apps:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payWithPaypal">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="${place.payPalEmail}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Order" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="${order.total}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU" />
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.com/${order.id}"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http:/mysite.com/cancel/${order.id}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com?oid=${order.id}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="oid" value="${order.id}" />
  <input type="image" onclick="javascript:sendUserDetailsByAjax('${order.id}');" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but5.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
</form>
```

Do you have any ideas about how I can make sure the `arrivalTime`, `name` and `email` get sent before the button redirects the page to PayPal.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the PayPal submit action to execute on the successful completion of your first form submit. So your can trigger sendUserDetailsByAjax function to make paypal submit to happen after the first form submit so that both would happen successfully one after the other.

```
function sendUserDetailsByAjax(orderId){

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var arrivalTime = $("#arrivalTime").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/order/updateuser",
        data: { 'orderId': orderId, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'arrivalTime': arrivalTime   },
        success: function(data){
              $('#payWithPaypal').submit();
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: I thought that should work as well. I've just tried it again. It seems that form still get's submitted first. So I changed the <input type="img" ... to <img .. i.e. so it wouldn't submit the form. But then the form never get's submitted.

Comment: I'm going to keep trying different versions.

Comment: When I say "never get's submitted" I mean there is no redirect and Firebug doesn't show any POST request/response

Comment: Not it will not get submitted if you use "<img". Now onclick of "<img" call the function "sendUserDetailsByAjax". check if there is any js error inbetween in Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

`("form").serialize` is a way to send information to your server of any form you include in your page.

You can get lot tutorial on that topic.